# Scaffolding Keyless Models on entity framework core 2.1

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.1

I have a simple console app and i am trying to scaffold all my models but i have some of them that does not have defined a primary key, Entity framework 2.1 give support to that kind of tables but still get this warning

```
Unable to identify the primary key for table 'dbo.myTable'.
Unable to generate entity type for table 'dbo.myTable'.
```

So then it doesn't generate the model

```
 dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=MyServer;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models -f
```

Am I missing Any parameter or any help to scaffold models with no primary key defined?

Comment: I know its a link but you have to specify something to help with identifying the item(s) in query.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/alternate-keys

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour. EF Core must need a PrimaryKey on table otherwise it will not Scaffold that table. So to generate model class from such table, you should add PK to the table.

Comment: I know that is the expected behavior but in 2.1 version they give support to tables without primary key
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#query-types

Unfortunaly i have an existing database and i cant make changes to any table

Comment: i installed github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools but unfortunately it doesn't generate those tables either, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This was not possible until EF core 3.0
You can test it on Ef core 3.0 which is currently in preview.

Comment: EF Core 3 is released and I was just able to scaffold a database with it (this database was with this same kind of problem), remember to upgrade related packages as `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design`, `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`